# Running a function via ngOnInit() does not work for ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic4

So, I want to run a function as soon as app loads. I am having trouble doing so in ionic 4.

I tried to work with `ionViewDidLoad` but that was deprecated in ionic4 and so I tried to work with `ngOnInit` and that also does not work for me.

I tried to get the latitude and longitude on the click of a button and it works fine, but I want it to show up automatically on the launch of my app.

My TS Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  lati: any;
  long: any;

  constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      this.lati = resp.coords.latitude;
      this.long = resp.coords.longitude;
     }).catch((error) => {
       console.log('Error getting location', error);
     });
  }
}
```

My HTML Code (Just the necessary part):

```
<p id="lat">Latitude is {{lati}}</p>
<p id="lon">Longitude is {{long}}</p>
```

Usually this should result in something like:

Latitude is MY_LATITUDE 
Longitude is MY_LONGITUDE

However it does not show my latitude and longitude (Just the paragraph content are shown).

I have tried searching with relevant keywords and implemented whatever I found but was simply not enough. (Considering ionic 4 is still pretty new and there is not much help available).

Please help me out so that the app returns longitude and latitude as soon as app starts.

Comment: Did you tried a breakpoint to see, if you're receiving valid data?

Comment: @Batajus I'm still learning these things. So would you please explain how to do that so that I can try working out on it? Also, I would like to point out that I am receiving valid coordinates when I fire the Cordova Geolocation via a Function triggered on a Button Click.

Comment: I just now tried your code (you are showing) with ionic 4, and it works just fine for me, so very hard to help...

Comment: @AJT_82 I know it should work, but apparently is not working. 

Comment: Please try and recreate the issue in a StackBlitz and I'd be happy to look at it :)

Comment: Here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ciym55

Comment: @KumarPriyansh I didn't see your comment until now, when I checked back. Remember to tag name :) I have no idea, why you had your component in main ts file. Seems you want it in some type of HomePage, so according to the stackblitz I put that there. Also you had the template code in app.html, so of course it wouldn't show there if you are calling data from another component. Get the geolocation in component and show the result in that component html. Here's stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-h9mts3?file=pages/home/home.html

Comment: @AJT_82 I messed up on stackblitz. But in my actual project, the component is in my home.ts file. My homepage is called home.html. Well, it console logs "Error getting location > PositionError {}"

Comment: Is that the whole error message - `"Error getting location > PositionError {}" `?

Comment: @AJT_82 Yes that's all. It's happening on Stackblitz.

Comment: Is it happening in both browser and device or just either?

Comment: It's just the browser. I didn't test on an actual device.

Comment: Hmm... just wondering about the error message it should tell us more actually, like: `"Error getting location > PositionError { code: 'some code here', message: 'some message here'}" `. If we have no error message it's actually impossible to help unless we can can reproduce the issue somewhere, like in a stackblitz. Which browser you using?

Comment: It's Google Chrome. I also tried with Safari though.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

I added an ***ionViewDidEnter*** function to my page.ts and the function Fired when the component being routed to has animated in.

For more information, you can see [Life Cycle Hooks](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/router-outlet)

```
 ionViewDidEnter() {
    console.log(" loading map");
    setTimeout(this.loadMap.bind(this), 1000);
    console.log(" loaded map");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnInit` will not be triggered if you come back to a page after putting it into a stack...

You can use one of next Lifecycle hooks:

`ionViewWillEnter` — Fired when entering a page (also if it’s come back from stack)

`ionViewDidEnter` — Fired after entering (also if it’s come back from stack)

Comment: `ion` Lifecycle hooks have been removed in ionic 4 in order to prefer `ng` hooks. Not quite helpful, but thanks anyway!

Comment: No, Ionic 4 has still this lifecycles (see in Github). Only ionViewDidLoad has been replaced with Angular Lifecycle (ngOnInit now). Also the two nav guards ( ionViewCanEnter and ionViewCanLeave) were removed because Angular Router provides route guards

Comment: So, If I asked for a solution for the above problem, using `ionViewWillEnter` and `ionViewDidEnter`, would you provide it? (Sorry, for my noobness).

Comment: Yes... Did you try to fix it with ionViewWillEnter, ionViewDidEnter?

Comment: Well, I just came across this "solution" and nope, it didn't work.